# How to get a string resource from a static Preference.OnPreferenceChange listener? Scared to mess up the autogenerated code

Tags: android, static, android-resources

Some code autogenerated in a SettingsActivity looks like this (abbreviated version):

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference.getKey().equals("notification_period")){
            preference.setSummary(stringValue + /* Resource: R.string.notification_period_summary*/));
        } 
        return true;
    }
};
```

I need to get the resource from strings.xml, but I don't think I have a context to use. I tried changing it to `SettingsActivity.this.getString(R...)`, but it said I couldn't do that from a static method. I tried adding a `Context context` to the method, but then it doesn't follow the signature it needs to override.

I'm not really sure where the method is being called from either, or if it is necessary for the signature to match for it to be called. There's another static method `private static void bindPeferenceSummaryToValue` Which contains this line of code:

```
sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
```

and I'm unsure what exactly that does either.

Comment: Where does that auto-generated code come from?

Comment: @Ridcully right click my package > new > activity > settings activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `Context` with the method `getContext()` of `Preference`:

```
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();

        if (preference.getKey().equals("notification_period")){
            String notificationPeriodSummary = preference.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.notification_period_summary);
            preference.setSummary(stringValue + notificationPeriodSummary));
        } 
        return true;
    }
};
```